# After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04 from 18.10 always showing the GRUB window. How can I fix it?

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, 19.04

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 but after that the GRUB is always showing.

Note: In my machine I'm only using Ubuntu.

Comment: I see that in a VM as well. a VM of 18.10 didn't show the GRUB menu but after upgrading to 19.04, the GRUB menu is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an temporary solution and applied. Now GRUB window is not showing.

The solution is:

1. Delete old kernel: I have deleted old kernel 4.18 by using Synaptic. [link](https://linoxide.com/booting/remove-old-kernel-versions-boot-menu)
2. Set GRUB_TIMEOUT = 0 at sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

[image]