# Ubuntu 19.04 - Grub Terminal On Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have a dual boot between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04. They are on separate SSDs with the boot info installed on the Ubuntu SSD

I have noticed that whenever I start or restart my computer from the Ubuntu side I am presented with the Grub terminal. I simply type in exit and then I am presented the menu and I can boot in to Windows or Ubuntu properly.

When I am in Windows and I hit restart , I get the grub menu straight away.

Its a minor annoyance getting that terminal but is there a way to fix it or should I just leave it alone ?

[image: Image of terminal at Boot]

Edit - Output from cat /etc/default/grub

here is the output of cat /etc/default/grub

```
~$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update

# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:

#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'


GRUB_DEFAULT=0

GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""


# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs

# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that 
obtains

# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)

#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"


# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)

#GRUB_TERMINAL=console


# The resolution used on graphical terminal

# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via 
VBE

# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'

#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480


# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to 
Linux

#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true


# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries

#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"


# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start

#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: You say  " I start or restart my computer from the Ubuntu side". I understand  "restart my computer from the Ubuntu side"  but how can you start your computer from the Ubuntu side? Also please edit and paste the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Already asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135432/after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-19-04-from-18-10-always-showing-the-grub-window-how-c

Comment: sorry Vijay here is what I mean :- when I shut down the computer from Ubuntu and then start it again, rather than a restart

Comment: @Vijay output of grub updated